# Observable next() callback not triggered

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to implement a global loading indicator that can be reused in the entire application. I have an injectable service that has the show and hide functions:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerOverlayService {
    private loaderSubject = new Subject<any>();


    public loaderState = this.loaderSubject.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    /**
     * Show the spinner
     */
    show(): void {
        this.loaderSubject.next(<any>{ show: true });
    }

    /**
     * Hide the spinner
     */
    hide(): void {
        this.loaderSubject.next(<any>{ show: false });
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the spinner overlay component. I'll exclude details about the HTML and CSS implementation as they're not important here.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { SpinnerOverlayService } from '../spinner-overlay.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'spinner-overlay',
  templateUrl: './spinner-overlay.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner-overlay.component.scss']
})
export class SpinnerOverlayComponent implements OnInit {

  show = false;

  private _subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private spinnerOverlayService: SpinnerOverlayService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._subscription = this.spinnerOverlayService.loaderState.subscribe((state) => {
        console.log("Subscription triggered.");
        this.show = state.show;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The problem: In the code of the overlay component I'm subscribing to the observable loaderState of the service. However when I call the show() function which triggers the next() of the observable, the subscription callback is not triggered.

This is how I call the show() function in the app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
               this.spinnerOverlayService.show();
}
```

What could I be missing? Seems really strange that the callback is not triggered.

Here is an example in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example-2qus3f?file=app%2Fspinner-overlay%2Fspinner-overlay.component.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you call `this.spinnerOverlayService.show();` before `spinner-overlay` is initialized. `Subject`s do not hold previous emitted value, so late subscribers won't get any value unless there is a new value.

One thing you can do is to change `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject` which emits the last value to new subscribers.

Or, you can call `this.spinnerOverlayService.show();` within `ngAfterViewInit`.
This way, you'll know `spinner-overlay` will get initialized and subscribe to `spinnerOverlayService.loaderState`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.spinnerOverlayService.show();
}
```

[Check it out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example-gvirnx?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer you can have a state in your spinnerOverlayService service to check the show hide and also have a subject to subscribe if new value is ready:

```
public state = { show: false };

    constructor() { }

    /**
     * Show the spinner
     */
    show():void {
      this.state = { show: true };
      this.loaderSubject.next(<any>{ show: true })
    }

    /**
     * Hide the spinner
     */
    hide():void {
      this.state = { show: false };
      this.loaderSubject.next(<any>{ show: false })
    }
```

and in your ngOnInit:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.spinnerOverlayService.state.show){
      console.log('Subscription triggeredd.');
    };
    this._subscription = this.spinnerOverlayService.loaderState.subscribe((state) => {
        console.log("Subscription triggered.");
        this.show = state.show;
      });
  }
```

OR you can use:

```
private loaderSubject = new ReplaySubject(1); // to cache last value
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example-mau6yg).